# Why is powershell slow on my machine?

Tags: powershell, powershell-v3.0

There are several virtual machines in the group, and 2 of them have really bad performance running Powershell.

A simple script like `powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion"` takes seconds on most of the machines, but 5+ minutes on 2 of them. Powershell version 3.0 btw.

As far as I can tell all the machines are configured the same. I've tried `ngen` the powershell binaries but that hasn't helped.

How do I figure out what's causing the poor powershell performance?

Comment: Download `procmon` from Sysinternals and monitor what is going on. Try to draw conclusions from there *(or post the trace for us to analyze)*

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something very similar to this myself. (I know it says slower in Server 2016 in the title, but we experienced it Windows 10 and other OS's too.)

[Link to https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3080e](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3080)
..

It was resolved by running "winrm quickconfig" in PowerShell as noted in the article. It worked for me personally. I know the commands we're running are a little different, but it might we worth a try.

Runtime for the command went from 2+ minutes to ~1 second.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! From looking over that issue, `winrm quickconfig` appears to enable "Windows Remote Management" service, which seems to speed up / fix certain powershell commands (like `Get-ComputerInfo`), but I don't think it improves powershell startup (which is what I was looking into when I came across this Q&A).